# How to determine a equivalence relation?

Tags: equivalence-relations

I have a problem to understand the following output:

Determine "representative system" or a "system of representatives" :).....for the following equivalence relation $R:=\lbrace{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)|y_1=y_2\rbrace}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$

With $ \lbrace{(0,x)|x \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace}$ as the "representative system"

Could someone please provide step to step explanation?

Comment: That last equality sign in your third line is  thrilling, @Googi...What did you **really** mean??

Comment: sorry...thats basically the answer that ist system of representatives = $ \lbrace{(0,x)|x \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace}$

Comment: As far as I can tell the the equivalence classes are just horizontal lines in the plane.

Comment: Well, don't write it thay way as what you wrote means that the cartesian product $\;\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2\;$ equals that, whic of course is absurd...

Comment: @JpMcCarthy, indeed...and that's what Googi wrote after explaining his notation.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of equivalence relation is to consider two objects to be the same provided they're  sharing a common property.  By abstracting -- that means in the literal sense overlooking -- that property we're able to construct new objects. (According to my knowledge this is due to H. Weyl.)

In our case we consider two points to be equal iff their second coordinates are the same.  In that sense $(4,3)$ equals $(-2311,3)$ equals any point whose second coordinate is $3$.  So all points equal to $(4,3)$ form a new object, namely the parallel line to the first coordinate axis through $(4,3)$.  Or through $(0,3)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: so in the present case the tuple (1,3) or (1,x) is also possible?

Comment: What do you mean by that, @Googi ? And why haven't you corrected your post, yet?

Comment: @Googi No, your tuples don't share the same *second* coordinate.